# why "~" not found in shell in this code？

Tags: shell

I am a new in shell.Here is the code:
[image]

when i execute 'zsh a'(the script's name),the result is:
[image]

Why the ‘~’ not found?Is '~' is command?Or it's because the environment variable？

Answer (score 1):

You should be specifying `zsh` in your shebang (`#!`) line - and you can use `/usr/bin/env` to determine where that is portably (ish). And the operators to compare numerical values are `-lt`, `-gt` and `-eq` for less than, greater than and equal. I would also prefer `printf` over `echo`. Putting it all together, I think you wanted

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh    
printf "Please enter an integer ->"
read A
B=99
printf "B=%d\n" $B
if [[ "$A" =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    if [[ "$A" -gt "$B" ]]; then
        printf "A>B (%d>%d)\n" "$A" "$B"
    elif [[ "$A" -lt "$B" ]]; then
        printf "A<B (%d<%d)\n" "$A" "$B"
    else
        printf "A=B (%d=%d)\n" "$A" "$B"
    fi
else
    printf "A (%s) is not an integer\n", "$A"
fi
```